# Differentiation to find power series representation for 1/(8+x)^2???

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm really confused about how to simplify the answer in this question- also, why do they change the index from n=0 to n=1 then back to n=0? Can someone explain when we need to change the index? In my answer I just stuck to n=0 the whole way through and I'm not sure I simplified it correctly at the end. Thanks!

[My answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwIrs.jpg)

The official answer[image]

Answer (score 0):

The change from $n=0$ to $n=1$ is because the $n=0$ term has a factor $x^0$.  This factor is constant and has zero derivative.  The change back to $n=0$ is explained in the text at the bottom.  They just made the substitution $n \to n+1$ because they liked the form of the answer better.  The term that used to have $n=1$ now has $n=0$.  If you look at the expression, you should be able to see that each term is the same in the new version.